# Cactus problem with discolouration

Tags: diagnosis, cactus

[image]Our 7ft high cactus has started to develop these brown patches & are definitely spreading. It’s located in a conservatory which is quite sunny but not direct & has been there for a number of years.
I’m sure it’s not water damage but I suppose it’s possible? Nothing has really changed environmentally for it.
We’ll be devastated if it perishes.

Comment: A picture might help.  Also, are any other plants in the area affected?

Comment: Picture added. Not really that ivf noticed.

Comment: There's a similar, but I think different, problem in [What are these brown spots on my cactus?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/31405/what-are-these-brown-spots-on-my-cactus)

Answer (score 1):

This is about 4' high, and grown from seed in 1983.

I can't remember a time when it didn't have those brown marks.
Given that they were the only indoor plants I'd ever grown, it didn't occur to me until now that it might be unusual.

I can't guarantee it's the same condition as yours, but for mine it's certainly not been fatal so far.

[image: Potted cacti with marks similar to those in the Question.]

[image: Close-up showing details of previous photo.]

Answer (score -1):

This is not good. Most certainly because of carbon monoxide concentration being high in your surroundings. How good is your ventilation? Do members in your family tend to sneeze a lot in the morning?

Comment: How did you diagnose CO poisoning for a plant? https://wgbis.ces.iisc.ac.in/energy/HC270799/HDL/ENV/enven/vol321.htm#:~:text=Plants%3A%20Carbon%20monoxide%20does%20not,which%20is%20used%20for%20photosynthesis.&text=ENVIRONMENTAL%20BEHAVIOUR-,Water%3A,the%20surface%20of%20the%20water.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: CO levels inside a conservatory ?  lLease post a reference or citation